# How can I create a .gitconfig file?

Tags: git, gitignore

I've cloned a brand new empty remote git repo which I need to put all my project files. Upon cloning I don't see the .gitconfig file, which I would like to set file exclusion.

I'm quite new to git and haven't created a repo by myself before.

Please help.

Comment: For excluding files i would start here https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

Comment: a .gitconfig file is simple a file called .gitconfig. i would recomend using `git config` though https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html

Comment: If you want to ignore certain files use `.gitignore` instead. [This](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) might help along with QuinnFTW's link above

Comment: all of your answers shaped to solve my problem, I was always thinking that .gitconfig file comes with the empty repo. Didn't think I could create this file locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A link that can be very helpful for you is the following:
[gitignore.io](http://www.gitignore.io/)

You'll find gitignore files for almost every kind of situation (XCode projects, Xamarin Studio,...)

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.